# How to write a delete rule on a view?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a rule on a view to delete tuples from the component tables, but so far can only remove data from one of them.  I've used postgres with basic views for a while, but I don't have any experience with rules on views.

I wrote a stupid little test case to figure out/show my problem. There's only one parent tuple per child tuple in this example (my actual schema isn't actually like this of course).

**Component tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE parent(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   p_data integer NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
CREATE TABLE child(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   parent_id integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES parent(id),
   c_data integer NOT NULL
);
```

**View:**

```
CREATE TABLE child_view(
   id integer,
   p_data integer,
   c_data integer
);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO child_view DO INSTEAD
   SELECT child.id, p_data, c_data 
      FROM parent JOIN child ON (parent_id=parent.id);
```

**Problem delete rule**

```
CREATE RULE child_delete AS ON DELETE TO child_view DO INSTEAD(
   DELETE FROM child WHERE id=OLD.id;
   DELETE FROM parent WHERE p_data=OLD.p_data;
);
```

The intent of the above rule is to remove tuples referenced in the view from the component tables.  The `WHERE p_data=OLD.p_data` seems odd to me, but I don't see how else to reference the desired tuple in the parent table.

Here's what happens when I try to use the above rule:

```
>SELECT * FROM child_view;
 id | p_data | c_data 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      1 |     10
  2 |      2 |     11
  3 |      3 |     12
(3 rows)

>DELETE FROM child_view WHERE id=3;
DELETE 0

>SELECT * FROM child_view;
 id | p_data | c_data 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      1 |     10
  2 |      2 |     11
(2 rows)
```

But looking at the parent table, the second part of the delete isn't working (id=3 "should" have been deleted):

```
>SELECT * FROM parent;
 id | p_data 
----+--------
  1 |      1
  2 |      2
  3 |      3
(3 rows)
```

How should I write the deletion rule to remove both child and parent tuples?

This is using postgres v9.

Any help is appreciated.  Also pointers to any materials covering rules on views beyond the postgres docs (unless I've obviously missed something) would also be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: as jmz points out, it would be easier to use a cascading delete than a rule here, but that approach doesn't work for my actual schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing with the rule problem is that the rule system doesn't handle the data atomically. The first delete is executed regardless of the order of the two statements in the DO INSTEAD rule. The second statement is never executed, because the row to which OLD.id refers to has been removed from the view. You could use a LEFT JOIN, but that won't help you because of the example table design (it may work on your actual database schema).

**The fundamental problem, as I see it, is that you're treating the rule system as it was a trigger.**

Your best option is to use foreign keys and `ON DELETE CASCADE` instead of rules. With them your example schema would work too: You'd only need on delete for the parent table to get rid of all the children.

Comment: +1. Use triggers. Rules are almost always the wrong solution, *unless* vetted by people with very good understanding of PostgreSQL internals. PostgreSQL developers have considered removing the rules system entirely and it will probably happen at one point. Good reading: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/06/15/to-rule-or-not-to-rule-that-is-the-question/

Comment: @intgr - Thanks for the links, very helpful. I see that there was a lot about rule behavior I had not considered.

Comment: Took me a while and re-reading the docs, but I think I see what you mean about misusing the rule system.  Too bad I can't use a cascading delete in my schema.  Think I'll be scrapping this approach.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do will work fine. But you made a left turn on this:

```
CREATE TABLE child_view(
   id integer,
   p_data integer,
   c_data integer
);
CREATE RULE "_RETURN" AS ON SELECT TO child_view DO INSTEAD
   SELECT child.id, p_data, c_data 
      FROM parent JOIN child ON (parent_id=parent.id);
```

You want a real life view here not a table. That is why delete will not work.

```
CREATE VIEW child_view AS SELECT
    child.id,
    p_data,
    c_data
    FROM parent
        JOIN child ON (parent_id=parent.id)
;
```

Replace the top with the bottom and it will work perfectly (It did when I tested it). The reason delete does not work is it trying to delete id from the `TABLE` child view which is of course empty! It does not execute  the 'select do instead' rule so it is working on the real table child view. People may poo-poo using rules but if they cannot see such an obvious mistake I wonder how much they know?

I have used rules successfully in defining interfaces to enforce business rules. They can lead elegant solutions in ways triggers could not.

Note: I only recommend this to make writable views for an interface. You could do clever things like checking constraints across tables - and you may be *asking for it*. That kind stuff really should be used with triggers.

Edit: script per request

```
-- set this as you may have had an error if you running 
-- from a script and not noticed it with all the NOTICES
\set ON_ERROR_STOP

drop table if exists parent cascade;
drop table if exists child cascade;

CREATE TABLE parent(
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        p_data integer NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE child(
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        parent_id integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES parent(id),
        c_data integer NOT NULL
);

        CREATE VIEW child_view AS SELECT
                child.id,
                p_data,
                c_data
                FROM parent 
                        JOIN child ON (parent_id=parent.id)
        ;

CREATE RULE child_delete AS ON DELETE TO child_view DO INSTEAD(
        DELETE FROM child WHERE id=OLD.id;
        DELETE FROM parent WHERE p_data=OLD.p_data;
);

insert into parent (p_data) values (1), (2), (3);
insert into child (parent_id, c_data) values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3);

select * from child_view;

 id | p_data | c_data 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      1 |      1
  2 |      2 |      2
  3 |      3 |      3
(3 rows)

delete from child_view where id=3;
DELETE 0

select * from child_view;
 id | p_data | c_data 
----+--------+--------
  1 |      1 |      1
  2 |      2 |      2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) The way I read the doc [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/rules-views.html) is that  `CREATE TABLE ...; CREATE RULE ...` and `CREATE VIEW` are equivalent and if the select rule was not getting called, no data would be returned (since I never put any in child view).  How do you reconcile this with your answer?  (2) I tried your suggestion with everything identical to my question except the definition of child_view (using yours) and I still get no deletion from parent.  Did you change anything else to get it to work?

Comment: 1) I agree but your not 'viewifying' child_view (I think this is where there is confusion). it is table and only one rule is called per query. On select it calls the rule which pulls the view. On delete it pulls the rule that tries to delete - *It does not call the select rule before* - so it materializes the empty table. 2) I'll post the script I used.

Comment: (1) Not following this, but I'll mull it over. (2) I ran the script you posted and the problem still persists in your version.  Run `select * from parent;` and you'll still see a tuple with id=3, i.e. the second delete in the rule is not functioning.