# Are modifiable join views a reasonable design choice?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rules

To be clear, by *modifiable **join** view* I mean a view constructed from the joining of two or more tables that allows insert/update/delete actions that modify any/all of the component tables.

This may be a postgres specific question, not sure.  I am also interested if other DBMSs have idiosyncratic features for modifiable join views, since as far as I can tell, they are not possible in standard SQL.

I'm working on a postgres schema, and some of my recent reading has suggested that it is possible to construct modifiable join views using instead rules (`CREATE RULE ... DO INSTEAD ...`).  Modifiable join views seem desirable since it would allow for hiding strong normalization behind an interface, providing a mechanism for classic abstraction.  Rules are the only option for implementation, since currently [triggers cannot be set on views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/rules-triggers.html).

However, the first modifiable view I tried to design ran into problems, and I find out that many consider non-trivial rules to be harmful (see links in comments to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534927/how-to-write-a-delete-rule-on-a-view/5536199#5536199)).  Also, I can't find any examples of modifiable join views on the web.

**Questions (Edit to put finer points on the questions):**

- Do you have any experience with modifiable join views and can you provide a concrete example with select/insert/delete/update ability?
- Are they practical, i.e. can they be treated transparently without having to tiptoe around mines/black holes?
- Are they ever a good design choice, in terms of functionality/effort ratio and maintainability?

Would greatly appreciate links to any examples/discussions on this topic.  Thanks.

Comment: Blog from one of the developers on views: http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/07/update-on-views.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have some experience with updatable views in general. I think they're practical in PostgreSQL. Like all design choices, they can be a good choice, and they can be a bad choice.

I find them particularly useful in dealing with supertype/subtype tables. I create one view for each subtype; the view joins the subtype to the supertype. Revoke permissions on the base tables, write rules for the view, and give client code access only to the views. All data manipulation done by client code then goes through the view and the rules defined on them.

I don't think rules are really different from any other feature in any other environment. And by *environment*, I mean C, C++, Java, Ruby, Python, Erlang, and BASIC, not just dbms environments.

**Use the good features of a language. Avoid the bad ones.**

"Don't use malloc()" is bad advice. "Always check the return value of malloc()" is good advice. "Never use rules" is bad advice. "Avoid using rules in ways that are known to have questionable behavior" is good advice. The rules you need for views on supertype/subtype tables are simple and easy to understand. They don't misbehave.

At the theoretical level, views provide logical data independence. But that's only possible if the views are updatable. (And many views *should* be updatable directly by the database engine, without any need of rules or triggers.)

Answer (score 2):

I use them as a replacement for ORMs. I think as long as you do not run-a-muck sprinkling them everywhere through the database they can be easy enough to understand. I define a schema for an application and then whatever views are in that schema are the methods and operations of that app. The client code can be mostly automated after that since the views give the abstraction I need to write generic client code.

People point out that the rule rewrite is not a real table (but it is posing as one) which makes it possible to write things that will break. This is possible but I have yet to come across it yet. The idea is to hide the complexity in the rewrite and then only do simple deletes and update with *no joins*. If it turns out that a join is needed - it is time to rewrite the rule, not the top level query.

At the end, I find it a very compact way to write the database. All the ways of interfacing with it are written as rules. No connection should have access to a real table. Your business logic is very explicit. If a view does not have an UPDATE rule for it - it can not be updated period. Since you have written all this in the database level instead of the client level, it is not tied to a web framework or a particular language. This leads to a lot of flexibility in how you want to connect to the database. Imagine you used web framework, but as time goes on you need direct access to the database for another source. Direct access will also bypass all of ORM business rules you worked so hard on. With a rule writing interface you can expose, the interface without fear that the new connection will corrupt the data.

If people say you can really F UP a database with them - then sure - of course you can. But you can with everything else too. If people say you can not use them at all with out mucking things up, then I would disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Two quick links:

1. [Why using rules is bad idea](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/06/15/to-rule-or-not-to-rule-that-is-the-question/)
2. [Triggers on views](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/10/16/waiting-for-9-1-triggers-on-views/)

Comment: I've seen your blog articles already, very informative.  Once pg 9.1 is released, triggers+views will be very nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use views only for reading data, (virtually) never for inserting or updating.  By essentially re-normalizing data (which sounds like what you are doing) in your database, you are likely creating a system that will be very difficult to test and maintain in the long term.

If at all possible, look at mapping your denormalized data back to a normal schema somewhere in your application code, and providing it to the database that way (to individual tables IMHO) in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I know in SQL Server if you update a view you must limit the change to only one table anyway which makes using views for updating useless in my mind as you have to know which fields go with which tables anyway.

If you want to abstract the information out and not have to worry about the database structure for inserts adn updates, an ORM mught do a better job for you than views.

Comment: You can put an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on views, and it could pick-and-choose which underlying tables to write what data to. Never done it myself, I think you'd have to have a *very* good reason to add that level of complex infrangibility to a system

Answer (score 0):

I have never used modifiable views of any sort but as you are asking whether they are a "reasonable design choice", can I suggest an alternative design choice with many benefits where modifiable views are not needed: a [Transactional API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092041/understanding-the-differences-between-table-and-transaction-apis/3092482#3092482)

Basically what this amounts to is:

- Users have no access to tables and cannot issue `insert`, `update`, `delete` statements at all
- Users have access to functions that represent well defined transactions - at the simplest level these may just do a single DML, but often would not. The important thing is that they map to transactions in the 'business' sense rather than in the 'database' sense
- For querying, users have access to (non-modifiable) views

Answer (score 0):

I do usually do views in the form of "last-valid-record" just hidding and tracking modifications (like a wiki)
The only drawback that I see to this is:  then you use your view as a table, and you join it with anything, and and you use it on "wheres", and you insert records on it, and so on, but behinds you have made lot of performance lost compared to the same acctions against a real table (more bigger and more complex). I think it depends on how many people must understud de schema. Its true that some DBMS also admit to index the views, but I think you lose an important amount of performance anyway.  Sorry about my english.